# How to include 3rd party library in Magento 2 (like php xlsx library)

Tags: magento2, pattern-library

How to include third party library like **php xlsx library** in Magento 2?

Since last 7 days I am browsing in google and I could not found any information.

Magento 2 give default framework module like parser, logger etc, I need to add export report in **xlsx format** in this case how to do it?

Comment: you want to add js library or php library?

Comment: @shaheer ali php library

Comment: place your php lib files into lib folder of the magetno or in your module folder and then include in your module file using require_once('path_to_your_lib_file');

Comment: @shaheer ,let me clarify :-i am creating custom libraries, for example take framework , we can  extend \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action right, in that way only i need to extend lib files like Magento\Framework\custom_library\library.(using require_once is different in this case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

below is the steps to create custom lib

in this i will take PHpexcel  lib

1. download the lib https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Classes
2. keep the folder in lib/internal
3. open PHPExcel.php and change the class name to  Phpexcel_PHPExcel
4. in side PHPExcel folder lot of function initialization  PHPExcel change it to Phpexcel_PHPExcel else it ill through error ex lib\internal\Phpexcel\PHPExcel\Calculation.php  __construct and getInstance function all PHPExcel  change to Phpexcel_PHPExcel like this change in all place
5. where ever your using use like

   ```
   use Phpexcel_PHPExcel;
   use Phpexcel_PHPExcel_IOFactory;
   ```

   and inside __construct

   ```
   Phpexcel_PHPExcel $xlsx,
   $this->excelFactory = $excelFactory;
   ```

   as like example you can build xlsx file

   ```
   public function getXlsxFile(){

       $component = $this->filter->getComponent();

       $name = md5(microtime());
       $file = 'export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.xml';

       $this->filter->prepareComponent($component);
       $this->filter->applySelectionOnTargetProvider();

       /** @var SearchResultInterface $searchResult */
       $component->getContext()->getDataProvider()->setLimit(0, 999999);
       $searchResult = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getSearchResult();

       $this->prepareItems($component->getName(), $searchResult->getItems());

       /** @var SearchResultIterator $searchResultIterator */
       $searchResultIterator = $this->iteratorFactory->create(['items' => $searchResult->getItems()]);
       $filterDataArr = '';
       foreach($searchResultIterator as $dataRow){
           $filterDataArr[]= $dataRow->getData();
       }

       $excelDataArray = '';
       $sheetTitle = 'export';
       $HeadersArray = $this->metadataProvider->getHeaders($component);     
       $FieldsArray = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);
       if(($key = array_search('actions', $FieldsArray)) !== false) {
           unset($FieldsArray[$key]);
       }

       if($component->getData('worksheetlabel')){
            $sheetTitle = $component->getData('worksheetlabel');
       }

       $hPos = 0;
       foreach($HeadersArray as $key =>$value){
           $excelDataArray[$hPos][$key] = $value;
       }

       $dPos = 1;
       if(count($filterDataArr) > 1){
           foreach($filterDataArr as $Filterdata){
               foreach($FieldsArray as $key=>$value){
                       $excelDataArray[$dPos][$key] = $Filterdata[$value];
               }
               $dPos++;
           }
       }

       $this->_Xlsx->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($excelDataArray, null, 'A1' );

       $this->_Xlsx->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($sheetTitle);
       $this->_Xlsx->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
       $callStartTime = microtime(true);

       $name = md5(microtime());
       $file = '/export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.xlsx';

       $this->directory->create('export');
       $objWriter = Phpexcel_PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->_Xlsx, 'Excel2007');
       $filepath = $this->directory->getAbsolutePath($file);
       $objWriter->save($filepath);

       return [
           'type' => 'filename',
           'value' => $file,
           'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
       ];
   }
   ```

Comment: In my opinion, `lib/internal` should not be touched. You can create `lib/external` instead.

Comment: Hello @peadeep , I want to add fPDF lib but not working http://www.fpdf.org/ as you told. Please suggest me proper way.

Answer (score 2):

what library exactly do you want to install?

The first result on google searching for php xlsx library gave me this: 
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Since its registered on packagist https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel

you can easily install it into your magento2 instance with the following shell command (from your magento2 root dir):

composer require phpoffice/phpexcel

If you are using it in a Magento Extension you should require the library in your Modules composer.json File, so it always is automatically installed when your Extension is installed.

The Autoloading will be handled by composer then

Comment: i want to include this library https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel actually looks like a modernized, composer compliant version of this :o. maybe you try it out?

Comment: @DavidVerholen :- once we download the xlxs lib and save in lib folder now how to use it in controller or  model file, is it right way include file model as Shaheer Ali told or write our own framework module as logger framework module is created

Comment: you don't have to download it manually. just install it with composer and you are good. you can then get an instance of the library as easy as any other magento class with the constructor dependency injection

Answer (score 1):

Place your php library files in lib folder of magento e.g your_magento/lib/phpxls
Now on top of your module file include the lib file using the below code

```
$object_manager = Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$dir = $object_manager->get('Magento\App\Dir');            
$base = $dir->getDir();
$lib_file = $base.'lib/phpxls/your_lib_file.php'
require_once($lib_file);
```

**Edit**
Create a file in your module helper folder e.g Mycustomlib.php
Now put the above code in start of Mycustomlib.php file looks like

```
$object_manager = Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$dir = $object_manager->get('Magento\App\Dir');            
$base = $dir->getDir();
$lib_file = $base.'lib/phpxls/your_lib_file.php'
require_once($lib_file);
namespace Yournamespace\Module\Helper;

class Mycustomlib extends Yourlibclass
{ 
}
```

you can extend the Mycustomlib where you want in your module

Comment: but in this case we need to include in every files in which file needed this .but magento 2 libraries are loaded automatically that way we need to configure right.. i want to load custom libraries at config level or auto load level.

Comment: you can use another approach . you can extend your model/helper file from your lib files and then you can use your model/helper file

Comment: if you don't  mind, can you explain clearly. because i am new to magento 2

Comment: check my answer now

Comment: @anandOntigeri did you tested above code?

Comment: This will not work. `namespace` should be first line in code file.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 supports **composer** installation for both modules and 3rd Party packages.

**PhpExcel** is **deprecated** now and the new **PhpSpreadsheet** should be use.

For installation via composer:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

For Reference: [phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation)