# call core php file function in magento 2 controller

Tags: magento2, php, custom

I am working on a API integration in magento2. That API have two php file with there own functions, that I want to call in our controller to implement respective process. 
I have placed that API library files in parallel with our controller file like  -

Our controller - app/code/Mycompany/CustomerAttribute/Controller/Coral/test.php

And library core php files -
app/code/Mycompany/CustomerAttribute/Controller/Coral/Lib/fileOne.php
app/code/Mycompany/CustomerAttribute/Controller/Coral/Lib/fileTwo.php

in our test.php controller file I am calling above files as -

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

**require 'Lib/fileOne.php';**
```

and trying to create object like this  -

```
$obj = new FileOne(array(
                        'appId' => $AppId,
                        'key' => $Key
                    ));
```

But after executing above statement its showing nothing;

Is this a right approach or I am doing something wrong in current method ?

Answer (score 0):

You must need to use Standard way to Implement Libs,for Example [how to include 3rd party library in magento 2 (like php xlsx library)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100766/how-to-include-3rd-party-library-in-magento-2-like-php-xlsx-library)

and that way you can access you function in your Extensions. with above way you can also update version of your lib.