# Regarding Magento Coding Standard Reject include_once statement

Tags: magento2, magento-coding-standard

I am using some third-party module file in my custom extension and need to include that .inc file via include_once but when I check that module via Magento 2 code standard check command.

It is showing me errors as the "include_once" statement detected. File manipulations are discouraged.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can design your extension another way. Why do you need to include that file? If it contains configuration values, use the `config.xml` for example

Comment: In this file there is no configuration setting . This iis my third-party liberary and Iwant to include this file into my custom module.

Comment: It seems that you can add that to lib/ https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100766/how-to-include-3rd-party-library-in-magento-2-like-php-xlsx-library